# GetItem on TDictionary eleminated by linker

Tags: delphi, linker, tdictionary

I am using a `TDictionary` of `<string, string>`.  But for some reason, the linker decides that I do not want to get items out of it.

I have the following code:

```
function TSheet.GetFieldName(Field: string; Default: string): string;
begin
  Result := Default;
  if FFieldNames[Field] = '' then
    Result := Field
  else
    Result := FFieldNames[Field];
end;
```

`FFieldNames` is a `TDictionary<string, string>`.  On line 2 (`if FFieldNames[Field] = '' then`), it throws a 'File not found' exception.  Adding `FFieldNames[Field]` to my watch tells me that *Function to be called, {System.Generics.Collections}TDictionary.GetItem, was eliminated by linker*.

[Someone asked here on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606105/how-do-i-force-the-linker-to-include-a-function-i-need-during-debugging) on how to avoid the linker eliminating functions during debugging.  From this I gathered, that the compiler/linker assumes that I am not using it.  Someone suggested - during conversation - that I should try using it *more*.

So I created the following code:

```
FFieldNames.Add(Name, S);
V := FFieldNames.Items[Name];
```

Where `S`, `Name` and `V` are strings.  This is from the code where `FFieldNames` is filled with data.  `V`'s only purpose is to obtain the just inserted `S`; it does nothing else.

Strangely, while the debugger tells me the same thing (i.e. `GetItem` being eliminated), `V` does get set to the expected value.  But it does not in my `TSheet.GetFieldName` function. :|

What am I missing?

Comment: I think your code is wrong anyway. If the key is not present then using `Items[]` will lead to an exception. You need `TryGetValue`. And you also need to make sure that you don't lookup the value twice. You want `if not FFieldNames.TryGetValue(Field, Result) then Result := Field;` Or perhaps what you mean is `if not FFieldNames.TryGetValue(Field, Result) then Result := Default;`. Also, `Result := Default` is pointless since you always overwrite. The compiler will tell you that if you switch on warnings.

Comment: This error only happens in the debugger which seems to get confused with generics. Your error is definitely not caused by the linker.

Comment: I realised my error just moments after I posted it; using `ContainsKey()` made it work!  But Heffernan's suggestion of `TryGetValue` is also a good idea.  Thanks for that.

Comment: I invariably find that I only ever use `TryGetValue`. Perhaps it's something about the dicts that I use, but I always want to handle the case of key not in dict using a boolean test rather than an exception. And I want to lookup the value and test for key in dict in a single operation for efficiency. Which means that I only ever use `TryGetValue`.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem applies to `TList<>`. Even if the code is using a method in the class it is not accessible from the debugger ("xxx on TList eliminated by linker"). I guess this is a problem with generics in general.

If you make a descendent class it will not have this problem

```
type
  TMyList = class(TList<TMyObject>)

  end;

var
  List : TMyList;
begin
  ...

end;
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I tried this approach on TDictionary<string, TObject> and it didn't work.  The relevant access methods were still eliminated by the linker.