# delphi Function to be called, TOleControl.GetIDispatchProp, was eliminated by linker

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control

Hello when I call TWebBrowser.Document properties, i am receiving this error message "Function to be called, TOleControl.GetIDispatchProp, was eliminated by linker" how to solve this problem.

I am trying to get document property , on clicking "a" element in browser dom.

```pascal
function TDocument.GetDocument: IDispatch;
begin
  FDocument := MainForm.Browser.Document;
  Result := MainForm.Browser.Document;
end;
```

Comment: You get that when executing the code? It's typically something you see when inspecting something in while debugging, and you can prevent it by unchecking 'optimization' in the project's compiler options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force the linker to include a function I need during debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606105/how-do-i-force-the-linker-to-include-a-function-i-need-during-debugging)